# How to render variable to view in slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have recommended_logger method in categories_contoroller, and I want to output @recommended_logger to a view file.

```
def recommended_logger
 @recommended_logger = User.joins(:categories).where(
   users: {user_type: 'star'},
   categories: {id: current_user.categries.first.id}
   ).first.name
end
```

In view file, I coded as below,

```
.recommended_loggers
  = @recommended_logger
```

It doesn't show anything. I'm very new to Rails, can someone please help?
Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: In which view you have that code?

Comment: I coded in categories/index.html.slim

Comment: Make sure it is not returning nil object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying display the output of `@recommended_logger` in `categories/index.html.erb`, you need to define `@recommended_logger` in `categories#index` method not in `recommended_logger` method.

```
#categories_controller

def index
  @recommended_logger = User.joins(:categories).where(
   users: {user_type: 'star'},
   categories: {id: current_user.categries.first.id}
   ).first.name
end
```

Comment: @Ryuji You are welcome! Mark the answer as accepted :)